# Rails deployment from foreman to supervisord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, supervisord

I would like to deploy my rails app, which locally runs with foreman to a server, where supervisord handles the restarts.

Unfortunatley the app throws this error and I have no idea where $PORT comes from, nor from where this part gets started. Locally everything runs nice.

My app uses redis (which is the second part in the procfile) and puma as a webserver

`.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:213:in 'initialize': the scheme tcp does not accept registry part: 0.0.0.0:$PORT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your supervisor config.

```
bundle exec puma -p $PORT
```

won't use the environment variable `PORT`. It should work setting the port manually. 
For example:

```
bundle exec puma -p 3000
```